# Linux terminal: how to achieve nice "tree" displays of e.g. lsblk output?

Tags: terminal, lsblk

what do I need to do to achieve a nice display output like this from lsblk?

[image: Example for beautiful output]

What I currently get is this rather ugly output:

[image: Example for "ugly" output]

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like it's a locale issue. I get same output as yours second with `LC_ALL=C` environment variable set. Look at your environment, see output of `env`, maybe you have a sort of `LC_*` variable set there. Try also `LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8 lsblk` just for example, your locale may be different than `en_US`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy, I found the answer.

It was the `locale` setting.

After enabling the `en_US UTF-8 locale` and also setting the environment variable `LANG` to `en_US.UTF-8`, `lsblk` output is just nice!